# Open vSwitch on Docker consumed higher %CPU than Open vSwitch on native Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, virtualization, docker

I have implement OVS on Docker container and transferred data from one host to another host through OVS. I also implemented OVS on an Ubuntu machine and transferred data one host to another host through OVS. I have observed that when I transferred data through OVS (on native ubuntu machine) it took low %CPU and when I transferred data through OVS (on Docker container) it took very high %CPU. I don't understand why the difference is so much. Can anyone explain it, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try LXD containers and OVS

The LXD/LXC containers will look/feel like working with a linux server so it is different than docker's approach but maybe its performance for your use-case will be better?

https://thomas-leister.de/en/container-overlay-network-openvswitch-linux/